# Download a PDF file from URL

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am writing a JavaScript function that download 10-15 PDFs from an array of URLs.
But for now lets try just one static file.

I have tried adding the file in a `<a>` tag like

I tried adding this to my page, the URL shows up and it downloads on click

```
<a href="" download="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" > download this</a>
```

I've also tried

```
<a href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" download="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" > download this</a>
```

But it always is corrupted.

I have tried several combinations.

P.S. The files aren't on current domain, they're on another domain

Comment: You have to set the `href` attribute to the URL, the `download` attribute can be used to specify a file name.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I've tried that, that doesn't seem to work

Comment: It does work just fine. Try not setting the filename at all, or setting it to something other than a URL

Comment: I've tried that with and without the filename, with and without the href and with and without the href tag, though the file gets downloaded, it shows its corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You should place that pdf file in secured location, see console log for the error: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: the actual files are sent over HTTPS, this sample file isnt, and the files do get downloaded

Comment: Then try solution as stated above, keep the download attribute but place url inside href tag.

Comment: <a href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" download>Download pdf here</a>

Comment: Also, please check your browser if that option is supported at all, https://caniuse.com/#search=download